# PHP Array Not Posting Correctly - Shows in Inspect but not in Dump

Tags: php

Issue:

My site has broken a page. It receives a POST from another page sending an array of check-boxes, this was working until earlier where I adjusted something in the code and now it's broken.

If I inspect the POST array sent to the page in Google Chrome:

```
campName: Correct
notes: Some Notes
userid: 47
userid: 45
userid: 43
userid: 44
```

This is correct, and relates to the checkboxes selected in the previous page,  however if I `var_dump($_POST['userid'])`, I only get a single value (the bottom one of the list).

My manipulation is also broken on the post-page with an error saying:

`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` relating to the `$_POST['userid']` even though it seems perfectly valid.

I've been staring at this for hours and can't work it out,  occurs on several browsers and machines.

The "campName" and "notes" are passed without issue and only the userid array seems to cause the issue.

Page accepting the post:

```
<?php
include_once 'header.php';
var_dump($_POST);

?>

<?php
if (!isset ($_POST['campName'])){
    header ('Location: /error.php/?err=You+must+enter+details+to+create+a+campaign');
}else{
$sql = "SELECT name FROM campaigns WHERE name=?";
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $_POST['campName']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
$num=mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($num!=0){

$jumbo = "<center>There is already a campaign with the name: <br></center> ";
} else{
    $jumbo = "Create: ";
}
}
?>


<div class="container" id="first-screen"> <!-- Main Container for Page-->
<div class="jumbotron">
<h1 class = "jumbotron-header">  <i> <center> <?php echo $jumbo . $_POST['campName']; ?> </strong></i></h1>
</div> <!-- Close Jumbotron-->
<p>You'll be creating this campaign with the following notes which will be available to all site members:</p>
<br>
<p class="font-weight-light"><? echo $_POST['notes']; ?> 
<P>  The following members will be assigned as committee members,  these can be changed as required in the admin panel.  Committee members will be alerted by SMS that the campaign has been 
created and that they have been assigned as committee members.</p>


<?php 

   $sql = "SELECT user_first, user_last FROM users WHERE user_uid =?";
   mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $_SESSION['username']);
   mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
   $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
   $data= mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result);
   echo '<strong>' . $data['user_first'] . ' ' . $data['user_last'] . ' ' . ' </strong> <br>';


foreach ($_POST['userid'] as $userid){

    $sql = "SELECT user_first, user_last FROM users WHERE user_id =?";
    mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $userid);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    $data= mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result);
    echo $data['user_first'] . ' ' . $data['user_last'] . ' ' . '<br>';

   }

?>
<div>
<a href="/createcampaign.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Restart</a>
<?php 

if($num==0){echo <<<EOT
    <form action="campcreate.php" method="post"
<button type="submit" name="create" class="btn btn-success" id="create">Finish</button>
</form>
EOT;
}
?>
</div> <!-- Button Div-->
</div> <!--Close main container-->


<?php
//Double check record will not be overwritten or double submission:
$sql="SELECT * FROM campaigns WHERE name=?";
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $_POST['campName']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($rows!=0){
     die;
}else{
    //Create a new record in the master campaigns list//
$sql="INSERT INTO campaigns (name, created) VALUES (?,?)";
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $_POST['campName'], $_SESSION['username']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

$tablename = "camp_" . $id;
echo $tablename;
//Create a new table for the campaign

$sql = "CREATE TABLE $tablename
    (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    notes VARCHAR(3000) NOT NULL
    )
    ";
    mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

// Insert data in to the newly created campaign table
$sql="INSERT into $tablename (id, name, notes) VALUES (?,?,?)";
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "iss", $id, $_POST['campName'], $_POST['notes']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

//Change Tablename

$tablename = "com_" . $id;
echo $tablename;

//Create Committee Table

$sql = "CREATE TABLE $tablename
    (
    id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    members VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    )
    ";
    mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    //Insert Committee Memebers

    foreach ($_POST['userid'] as $userid){
        $sql="INSERT into $tablename (members) VALUES (?)";
        mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $userid);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }
    //Insert extra line for originator to committee list

    $sql="INSERT into $tablename (members) VALUES (?)";
    mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $_SESSION['id']);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }

//Close Function



?>
```

Post coming from:

```
<?php
include 'header.php';
?>

<div class="container" id="first-screen"> <!-- Main Container for Page-->
<div class="jumbotron">
<h1 class = "jumbotron-header"> Manage Campaigns </h1>
</div> <!-- Close Jumbotron-->
<p>Create, modify or delete campaigns from the project.  This page is only available to site <strong>administrators</strong></p>
<p>Campaigns fall in to two groups,  either main campaigns or sub-campaigns.  For example PimJam 2019 could be a main campaign with fun-raiser events added as sub-campaigns.</p>
<p>Campaigns bind all site data together so it is VITAL that these are correctly ordered and maintained, deleting a campaign can disastiousy damage data on the website and should only be performed under recomendation 
of <strong>shitpostwizard</strong>.
<div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="create">Create a new Campaign</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Create a new Sub-campaign</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete a Campaign</button>
</div> <!-- Button Div-->
</div> <!--Close main container-->




<div class="container collapse" id="create-screen"> <!-- Main Container for Page-->
<div class="jumbotron">
<h1 class = "jumbotron-header"> Create a new campaign </h1>
</div> <!-- Close Jumbotron-->
<p>Enter the details below to create a new campaign.  Please ensure it is a new campaign which is required, not a new sub-campaign.</p>
<div> <!--Form Div-->
<form action="campcreate.php" class="form" method="post">
<label for "campName">Campaign Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="campName" class="form-control" name="campName" placeholder="Campaign Name" required minlength="6" autofocus>
<label for "notes">Description:</label>
<textarea class="form-control" name="notes" rows="5" id="notes" placeholder="Add any useful notes or descriptions here"></textarea>
<h3>Select committee memmbers:</h3>
<p>Committee members can be changed as required,  all members selected as committee members will be able to view documents, meetings etc. connected to the campaign.</p>
<p>Assigning a committee member does <strong>not</strong> grant them any different admin privillages on the site.</p>
<?php getnames(); ?>

<div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success float-right" id="create">Create</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right" id="restart">Back</button>
</div> <!--Form Div--->
</form>

</div> <!-- Button Div-->
</div> <!--Close main container-->


<script>
    $("#restart").click(function(){
    $("#create-screen").hide();
    $('#first-screen').fadeIn(200);
});
</script>




<script>
    $("#create").click(function(){
    $("#first-screen").hide();
    $('#create-screen').fadeIn(200);
});
</script>



?>
```

Checkboxes being generated in functions.php:

```
function getnames(){
    global $conn;
$sqlga = "SELECT user_id, user_first, user_last FROM users WHERE (usr_acrive= 1) AND (perm!=0) ORDER BY user_last ASC";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);    
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sqlga);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($row['user_id']!=$_SESSION['user_id']){
        $checked="";
    }else{
        $checked="checked disabled";
    }
        $i++;
    echo '<input type="checkbox"'.$checked.' value="'. $row['user_id'] .'" name="userid"'. $i. '> '.$row['user_first'] . ' '. $row['user_last'] . '<br>';
   }
}
```

Any pointers for diagnosis?

Comment: Please edit and post the code so we can help diagnose.

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" name="userid[]" />` - if you want an array, use `[]` on the element name. Otherwise, each duplicate key will overwrite the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

```
echo '<input type="checkbox"'.$checked.' value="'. $row['user_id'] .'" name="userid"'. $i. '> '.$row['user_first'] . ' '. $row['user_last'] . '<br>';
```

To:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox"'.$checked.' value="'. $row['user_id'] .'" name="userid[]"'. $i. '> '.$row['user_first'] . ' '. $row['user_last'] . '<br>';
```

When trying to submit an array of values all with the same `name` . You should use the array operator `[]` to make sure the values don't override each other on submission.

I think that should solve your problem.